# jQuery - Dropdown list becomes empty after change and form submit

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, asp.net-mvc

I have a dropdown which reloads the page with some new data after user selection is made. When a change/selection and submission are made in the dropdown, page reloads and dropdown becomes **empty**. I would like to **keep the dropdown data after submission and display what the user has selected**. Thanks in advance for any help, I am new to this.

```
$( document ).ready(function() {
    $("#ddlConsumer").change(function () {
        var selected = $("#ddlConsumer :selected").text();
        localStorage.setItem("selected", selected);
        $("#paymentform").submit();

    });
});

var selectedConsumer = localStorage.getItem("selected");
console.log(selectedConsumer);
$("#ddlConsumer").val(selectedConsumer);
```

The HTML part:

```
<td>
    <div class="form-group">
        <label class="col-sm-4 control-label">Consumer: <span>*</span> </label>
        <div class="col-sm-6">
            @Html.DropDownList("ConsumerID", (SelectList)ViewBag.Consumer, new { id = "ddlConsumer", @class = "form-control"}) 
        </div>
    </div>
</td>
```

Comment: I don't know what your dropdown text/values look like, but I can see that you are saving off the .text() and not the .val(). Then you are setting the dropdown val = the text of the selected option. If the text does not match the value, you won't get the selected option

Comment: Also, all of your js code shown above should be in the doc.ready(). The $("#ddlConsumer").val(selected) could be getting executed before Razor renders the dropdownlist

Comment: I've added .val(), but end up in the same place. Also just tried to add everything in doc.ready(), except of the last line. Still can't figure it out. :(

Comment: The last line is the most important line to have in the doc.ready ...

Answer (score 0):

One thing you should be aware is the fact that the HTTP protocol is stateless.
This means that, once you've sended the form the page will be reloaded and the values will be lost.
To solve this you can do two things:

1 - Send the for asyncronously using $ajax. Like:

```
$("#ddlConsumer").change(function () {
    var selected = $("#ddlConsumer :selected").text();
    localStorage.setItem("selected", selected);

    $.post('yourUrlAction', $('#TesteForm').serialize(), function () {
        //Here you can manipulate the code after a successfull call
    });
});
```

2 - Get the values in the backend and send them back as a result of the post. This varies based on what technology you're using as backend, but in .net MVC would be like:

```
[HttpPost]
public ActionResult Index(string field)
{
    ViewBag.Value = field;
    return View();
}
```

And in the View:

```
<input name="field" id="field" type="text" value="@ViewBag.Value" />
```

Hope that helps.